# Charts - ScatterChart 1:1 Axis Scale

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want to plot some x and y data inside a `ScatterChartView`, but I can't seem to figure out how I can set my x- and y-axis to be scaled equally.

I have tried to use the height and width of the chart to calculate both axes min and max values independently, but that was quite messy and did not lead to any good result.

Do you have any suggestions? Have I overlooked anything inside the documentation?

Underneath is my SwiftUI view I'm using as my scatter plot.

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ScatterPlot: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = ScatterChartView

    private let plot = ScatterChartView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ScatterChartView {
        setUpPlot()
        return plot
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ScatterChartView, context: Context) {}

    private func setUpPlot() {
        plot.rightAxis.enabled = false
    
        let dataSets = [getScatterPlotDataSet()]
        let data = ScatterChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    
        plot.data = data
    }

    private func getScatterPlotDataSet() -> ScatterChartDataSet {
        let entries: [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0), ChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 1)]
        let dataSet = ScatterChartDataSet(entries: entries)
    
        return dataSet
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @unknown Some information to the one systematically going through the trouble of downvoting all my answers where I used the phrase "Thanks in advance". Just to get this straight I'm not a native English speaker and in no way want to force someone into answering my questions. In german, this is considered to be a very polite way of asking someone to answer your question. I'm sorry if this was misunderstood. In case the one that this is addressed too sees this, please consider reading the following answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98152/472396

Comment: Can you share what Code you have done and some example of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to calculate the width and height ratio and get this result

please note I using storyboard for this example, you need to check are you get correct chart width and height in your swiftUI code

```
    chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
    
    let width = chart.frame.width
    let height = chart.frame.height
    
    let maxValue: Double = 1.0
    
    chart.xAxis.granularity = 0.5
    chart.leftAxis.granularity = 0.5
    
    chart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = maxValue
    chart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chart.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(width / height) * maxValue
```

[image]